# Override vendor/magento/module-customer PHTML file

Tags: theme, magento2.2, custom-theme

Magento 2.2.

I have a theme:

```
/app/design/frontend/Companyname/Newtheme/
```

I would like to override this PHTML file:

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml
```

What is the correct directory structure in my theme's folder to put my new file?

**I have tried:**

```
/app/design/frontend/Companyname/Newtheme/Magento_Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml
```

and

```
/app/design/frontend/Companyname/Newtheme/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml
```

and

```
/app/design/frontend/Companyname/Newtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml
```

p.s.
I know this is a really basic question, I am just not understanding the documentation and many examples online. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correct Folder path**.. You have mention 2 times `frontend`...

> app/design/frontend/Companyname/Newtheme/Magento_Customer/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml

Don't forget to run

```
setup:static-content:deploy
cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be.

```
/app/design/frontend/Companyname/Newtheme/Magento_Customer/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml
```

No need to add view/frontend to your custom theme.